# System of autonomous ODEs with polynomial right hand side

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hello I'm wondering if it is possible to find solution to this system of ODEs:
$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = f(x,y,z) \\ \frac{dy}{dt} = g(x,y,z) \\ \frac{dz}{dt}=h(x,y,z)$$

where $f,g,h$ are second degree polynomials in three variables. When I have just one equation $x' = f(x)$ I can solve it by separation of variables. But I'm perplexed what to do with three of them. I guess when if I would have only two I could do some magic with complex number in some special case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible only in special cases. If all three functions are linear, then closed form solutions can indeed always be found, since the corresponding characteristic equation has roots that can be expressed in radicals.

As soon as there is a quadratic term, this is usually no longer possible. The simplest example that I know is the Roessler system
$$
f(x,y,z) = -y-z, \quad g(x,y,z) = x + ay, \quad h(x,y,z) = b + zx - cz
$$ 
with  $a, \, b, \, c \in \mathbb{R}$.  There is exactly one second order term in one of the right hand sides. The system has a strange attractor for suitable parameters which pretty much excludes the possibility of a closed form solution.

--edit--

If the system is nonlinear, you can try linearizing to get "good" approximations near equilibrium points. This is done by evaluating the Jacobian matrix $J(x,y,z)$ at a particular fixed point. For more, an example you might want to look at is the classic "competitive species problem":

http://people.whitman.edu/~hundledr/courses/M244S07/Ch9Notes.pdf